# How to rename attachments with sender's name in outlook

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to make an outlook vba to download attachments from selected emails in outlook and rename them to include unique words to identify each sender. So far, I have managed to do so except for the last part.

For example,
if I receive an email from asdf@asdf.com(unique identifier: Company A) with an attachment(order.xlsx), then download the attachment and rename it to 'Company A - order.xlsx'.

It would be a great help if someone could solve this issue.

Thank you in advance!

```
Public Sub save_attchments()
  Dim coll As VBA.Collection
  Dim obj As Object
  Dim Att As Outlook.attachment
  Dim Sel As Outlook.Selection
  Dim Path$
  Dim i&
  Dim itm As Outlook.MailItem
  
  Path = "\\~~\~~\" & Format(Date, "yymmdd") & "\"
  On Error Resume Next
  MkDir Path
  On Error GoTo 0

  Set coll = New VBA.Collection
  
  If TypeOf Application.ActiveWindow Is Outlook.Inspector Then
    coll.Add Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
  Else
    Set Sel = Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
    For i = 1 To Sel.Count
      coll.Add Sel(i)
    Next
  End If

  For Each obj In coll
    For Each Att In obj.Attachments
      Att.SaveAsFile Path & " - " & Att.FileName
            
    Next
  Next

  Shell "Explorer.exe /n, /e, " & Path, vbNormalFocus
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I use to save attachments from selected e-mails. I have updated it to allow a prefix addition to the file save names which you should be able to adapt to your needs. A suffix is more involved so currently omitted.

```
Public Sub SaveAttachmentsSelectedEmails()
    Dim olItem As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim olSelection As Outlook.Selection: Set olSelection = ActiveExplorer.Selection
    Dim FilePath As String: FilePath = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Documents\Documents\Attachments"
    
    If Dir(FilePath, vbDirectory) = "" Then
        Debug.Print "Save folder does not exist"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    For Each olItem In olSelection
        SaveAttachments olItem, FilePath, RemoveAttachments:=False
    Next olItem
End Sub

Private Function SaveAttachments(ByVal Item As Object, FilePath As String, _
    Optional Prefix As String = "", _
    Optional FileExtensions As String = "*", _
    Optional Delimiter As String = ",", _
    Optional RemoveAttachments As Boolean = False, _
    Optional OverwriteFiles As Boolean = False) As Boolean
    
    On Error GoTo ExitFunction
    
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, FileName As String, Flag As Boolean
    Dim Extensions() As String: Extensions = Split(FileExtensions, Delimiter)
    If Right(FilePath, 1) <> "\" Then FilePath = FilePath & "\"
    
    For j = LBound(Extensions) To UBound(Extensions)
        With Item.Attachments
            If .Count > 0 Then
                For i = .Count To 1 Step -1
                    FileName = FilePath & Prefix & .Item(i).FileName
                    Flag = IIf(LCase(Right(FileName, Len(Extensions(j)))) = LCase(Extensions(j)), True, False)
                    Flag = IIf(FileExtensions = "*" Or Flag = True, True, False)
                    If Flag = True Then
                        If Dir(FileName) = "" Or OverwriteFiles = True Then
                            .Item(i).SaveAsFile FileName
                        Else
                            Debug.Print FileName & " already exists"
                            Flag = False
                        End If
                    End If
                    If RemoveAttachments = True And Dir(FileName) <> "" And Flag = True Then .Item(i).Delete
                Next i
            End If
        End With
    Next j
    SaveAttachments = True

ExitFunction:
End Function
```