# Finding specific email Subject in Outlook sub folder and download attached files from the email

Tags: vba, email, outlook, filtering, email-attachments

I have managed to make macro that downloads attachments files from my Inbox sub folder in Outlook, but it seems i can't make it works for specific combination of symbols in the email subject.
I need to download only the attachments from email that contains "906" in the Subject name. Can someone makes the modification i need for this task, please? I'm stuck already in my code :

```
Sub SaveMail()

SaveEmailAttachmentsToFolder "Meteologica SA Power Forecast", "csv", ""

End Sub
Sub SaveEmailAttachmentsToFolder(OutlookFolderInInbox As String, _
                             ExtString As String, DestFolder As String)
Dim ns As NameSpace
Dim Inbox As MAPIFolder
Dim SubFolder As MAPIFolder
Dim item As Object
Dim Att As Attachment
Dim FileName As String
Dim MyDocPath As String
Dim I As Integer
Dim wsh As Object
Dim fs As Object
Dim strAttachmentName As String

On Error GoTo ThisMacro_err

Set ns = GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set Inbox = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set SubFolder = Inbox.Folders(OutlookFolderInInbox)

I = 0
' Check subfolder for messages and exit of none found
If SubFolder.Items.Count = 0 Then
    MsgBox "There are no messages in this folder : " & OutlookFolderInInbox, _
           vbInformation, "Nothing Found"
    Set SubFolder = Nothing
    Set Inbox = Nothing
    Set ns = Nothing
    Exit Sub
End If


For Each item In SubFolder.Items
    For Each Att In item.Attachments
        If LCase(Right(Att.FileName, Len(ExtString))) = LCase(ExtString) And InStr(strAttachmentName, "906") > 0 Then
            DestFolder = "C:\Users\Confi-005\OneDrive - confi.com\Desktop\Schedule\Mail_Temp\Download\"
            FileName = DestFolder & item.SenderName & " " & Att.FileName
            Att.SaveAsFile FileName
            I = I + 1
        End If
    Next Att
Next item

If I > 0 Then
    MsgBox "You can find the files here : " _
         & DestFolder, vbInformation, "Finished!"
Else
    MsgBox "No attached files in your mail.", vbInformation, "Finished!"
End If


ThisMacro_exit:
Set SubFolder = Nothing
Set Inbox = Nothing
Set ns = Nothing
Set fs = Nothing
Set wsh = Nothing
Exit Sub


ThisMacro_err:
MsgBox "An unexpected error has occurred." _
     & vbCrLf & "Please note and report the following information." _
     & vbCrLf & "Macro Name: SaveEmailAttachmentsToFolder" _
     & vbCrLf & "Error Number: " & Err.Number _
     & vbCrLf & "Error Description: " & Err.Description _
     , vbCritical, "Error!"
Resume ThisMacro_exit

End Sub
```

Comment: You may find the following answer on an alternate question which downloads the attachments from e-mails that have been selected. You could simply do a search in Outlook for "906", select the e-mails you want the attachments from, then trigger the macro. https://stackoverflow.com/a/68652604/3688861

Comment: There is no `strAttachmentName`. You could assign a value of `Att.FileName` to  `strAttachmentName` or apply directly `And InStr(Att.FileName, "906") > 0`

Comment: @niton Thank you!! It was just the spot-on correction for my issue!

Answer (score 0):

Iterating over all items in the folder is not really a good idea:

```
For Each item In SubFolder.Items
    For Each Att In item.Attachments
```

Instead, you need to use the `Find`/`FindNext` or `Restrict` methods of the `Items` class where you can deal only with items that correspond to the specified search criteria. You may find these methods described in depth in the articles that I wrote for the technical blog:

- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)

For example, you may use the following search criteria to find items with a specific phrase in the `Subject` line:

```
criteria = "@SQL=" & Chr(34) _ 
& "urn:schemas:httpmail:subject" & Chr(34) _ 
& " ci_phrasematch 'question'"
```

Read more about that in the [Filtering Items Using a String Comparison](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/how-to/search-and-filter/filtering-items-using-a-string-comparison) article.

Comment: @EugenAstafievi will try this method of `Find/FindNext`. It has to be integrated inside my code i suppose?

Comment: Yes, of course, you need to replace the for each loop with these methods. So, you can iterate over items that corresponds to your conditions (with the required subject line).

Comment: I will try to manage this, since the solution niton gave early on, doesn't take all the emails with 906 in the subject, but only some of them.

Comment: Iterating over all items in the folder is not a proper way of getting items.